# Android: Is it possible to set a badge like iPhone in Android?

Tags: android

I am implementing an app in which i need to set a badge on the tab? Do we have a default badge setting in android like iPhone? How can i do that?
Please help me in this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit default the appearance of tabs in android?

Comment: No. What i want is iam adding 3 customised tabs to my app. On the top of middle tab i want to add badge to display the notification text. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This project on [github](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) sounds like what you're looking for.